# How to graph an iteration method?

Tags: python

In the following code I have implemented the bisection method in Python. Just as a general overview my code does the following:

- My function is able to find the root of an arbitrary continuous scalar valued function f as a lambda function a prescribed function tolerance.
- My routine finds the root of the function f(x) = cos x - sin x on the interval [0,1] with tolerance 10^{-14}
- Records how many iterations it takes to reach this tolerance.

**However now I am looking to plot the convergence diagram on that same interval. This would be the absolute error as a function of the number of iterations.**

To do this I must collect the series of error figures in a list, and plot that against a list of the integers 1 through your final value of iter.

I am looking for some help with this as I am stuck. I have made another 2 codes with different iteration methods so once I can see how it works on this one I should be able to implement it on the others also! All help is greatly appreciated

```
import math
def root(x):
    return(math.cos(x)-math.sin(x))

def bisection_method(f, a, b, tol):
    if f(a)*f(b) > 0:
        #end function, no root.
        print("No root found.")
    else:
        iter = 0
        while (b - a)/2.0 > tol:
            midpoint = (a + b)/2.0

            if f(a)*f(midpoint) < 0: # Increasing but below 0 case
                b = midpoint
            else:
                a = midpoint

            iter += 1
        return(midpoint, iter)

answer, iterations = bisection_method(root, 0, 1, 10**(-14))
print("Answer:", answer, "\nfound in", iterations, "iterations")
```

Comment: What graphing/plotting library are you using? Please [edit] your question and show your own attempt at using it.

Comment: The agbsolute error, or the answer?

Comment: absolute error.

Comment: @martineau I am not sure how to start!

Comment: but thanks for your edit

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem would you be able to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well instead of generating a result, you can make this an *iterable* that each time yields a 2-tuple with the absolute error, and the iteration, like:

```
def bisection_method(f, a, b, tol):
    if f(a)*f(b) > 0:
        #end function, no root.
        print("No root found.")
    else:
        iter = 0
        while (b - a)/2.0 > tol:
            midpoint = (a + b)/2.0
            yield iter, abs(f(midpoint))
            if f(a)*f(midpoint) < 0: # Increasing but below 0 case
                b = midpoint
            else:
                a = midpoint
            iter += 1
```

This for example yields:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(list(bisection_method(root, 0, 1.57, 10e-4)))
array([[0.00000000e+00, 5.63088062e-04],
       [1.00000000e+00, 5.40415665e-01],
       [2.00000000e+00, 2.75209010e-01],
       [3.00000000e+00, 1.37986732e-01],
       [4.00000000e+00, 6.87946039e-02],
       [5.00000000e+00, 3.41260256e-02],
       [6.00000000e+00, 1.67827312e-02],
       [7.00000000e+00, 8.10997409e-03],
       [8.00000000e+00, 3.77346075e-03],
       [9.00000000e+00, 1.60518823e-03]])
```

We can then plot this as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array(list(bisection_method(root, 0, 1, 10e-14)))
plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
plt.show()
```

This gives us, for a range of [0,1], the following plot:

[image: error progression of the bisect method]

Note however that the initial range can of course have a huge impact: if the midpoint is exactly located at the root, then this of course will only require one iteration. Furthermore like the error shows, the next absolute error is not per se smaller than the previous one. The method guarantees improvement over a "long time" (well typically the error will only increase one or two iterations, so "long" is here quite relative).

The above is not very informative, since the error quickly drops below a noticable value, so we do not see much of the error after a certain number of iterations. We can use a log-scale, to make the details at the end more clear:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array(list(bisection_method(root, 0, 1, 10e-14)))
plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

we then see that the error drops as follows:

[image: logplot of the error progression]

Comment: np.array(list(bisection_method(root, 0, 1.57, 10e-4))) in this why did you choose 0, 1.57?

Comment: @fr14: because otherwise the number of elements in the result would be quite large, and that would of course not be very useful in an answer.

Comment: and the second graph still shows between the interval 0,1?

Comment: @fr14: yes, because a plot of course allows more data to be plotted.

Comment: last question, should there be titles on the x and y axis of your graphs? how would I implement those in

Comment: @fr14: take a look at the `pyplot` manual: https://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: should the y axis represent the error? what would the x axis be, if you could edit that in it would be great

Comment: @fr14: the Y-axis is the absolute error, the X-axis is the iteration.

Comment: that makes sense! when I use your code I am getting that a is not defined as a error in this part of the code plt.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1])

Comment: @fr14: forgot to edit, it should be `data` instead of `a`.

Comment: gotcha, works perfectly now! I will try and figure out those axis, thanks for your help!